# Show notification in angular5 app

Tags: angular, angular5, frontend

I'm working in a simple app angular5, I want to show to users some notification like in this picture bellow:

[image]

I'm not able to find any simple tutorial so I can do as this in my app.
Can you help me with any helpful links? As I'm learning angular5.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own component , in this case you need to create two components

(i) Navigation bar component
(ii) Notification component.

For the notificaiton component, you can use ngFor and loop over the collection to display the notificaiton.

Comment: But how can show that there is a new notification etc ? i'm not sur exactly on how to do all of this .

Comment: actually its a huge task

Comment: exactly , can you help me with a any helpful link of an exemple ?